# Verificação de estilos que não estão sendo utilizados em um site

Tags: css

Conheço algumas ferramentas para verificar em um site quais estilos css não estão sendo usados, mas nenhuma delas na minha opinião é realmente completa, alguém conheça alguma do gênero para me indicar?

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361007/is-there-a-way-to-check-which-css-styles-are-being-used-or-not-used-on-a-web-pag

Comment: Olá Munir, para aumentar as chances de obter uma boa resposta eu recomendaria reformular um pouco sua pergunta. Do jeito que está ela corre o risco de ser fechada como "Baseada em opiniões" ou "Não está clara o suficiente", ainda que eu acredite que seja uma pergunta válida. Talvez seja mais fácil te dar uma resposta entendendo quais requisitos você procura em uma ferramenta de suporte.

Answer (score 3):

Umas boa maneira de começar é com [a ferramenta de auditoria do Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#audits).

Para usá-la:

1. Abra as ferramentas para desenvolvedores (`Ctrl+Shift+I` no Windows e Linux)
2. Clique na aba *Audit*.
3. Selecione *Web Page Performance*
4. Clique em *Run*

O Chrome apresenta todas as regras não utilizadas na página:

[image: Auditoria do Chrome]

Comment: Não conhecia essa ferramenta do Chrome, acabei de testar realmente muito útil

Comment: Muito Bom! Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tem essa que é muito boa, funcionar no firefox

https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/css-usage/

Comment: Bacana também! Obrigado.